# Decoding "strange" utf32 format

Tags: c#, decoding, utf-32

I have a file containing UTF32 that was read from a database.
I would expect "Hi" to become `H\0\0\0i\0\0\0`, however it actualy is `\0\0\0H\0\0\0i`, with the null chars in front.

Does anyone know how this could happen, and how i can decode this leaving all data intact?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm using c#

Comment: Is this a big endian database? How do you read that data?

Comment: Not sure, i just got the csv file and have to deal with it...

Comment: Excel has no problem handling the format btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be getting utf-32 in network byte order rather than the reverse order you are expecting. Either order is valid for utf-32.

What byte order the database uses when you ask for utf-32 will probably be controlled by a that db's configuration.

You can use [IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder.aspx) to convert a single code point, or [UTF32Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzs928d7.aspx) with appropriate byte order to convert strings:

```
        var bytes = new byte[] {0,0,0,(byte)'H',0,0,0,(byte)'i'};
        var encoding = new UTF32Encoding(true, false);
        var text = encoding.GetString(bytes);

        Console.WriteLine(text);
```